# Trying to query certain groups that satisfy a value_count condition

Tags: pandas, group-by

I'm playing around with stock data, and I'm trying to filter the groups that have more buys than sells with respective to `Transaction` values

So the code I'm running to display the below  data is

```
df.groupby('Stock').Transaction.value_counts()
```

data

```
Stock  Transaction    
ADC    Buy                 2
AKAM   Option Exercise    51
       Sale               34
       Buy                 9
AMNB   Buy                10
ARCC   Buy                15
ARL    Buy                12
ASA    Buy                 7
ASRV   Buy                12
       Option Exercise     1
AUBN   Buy                 4
       Sale               11
BAC    Option Exercise    23
       Buy                15
       Sale                7
BCBP   Buy                 3
       Sale               11
BKSC   Buy                55
BMRA   Buy                 5
       Option Exercise     3
       Sale                1


                      ..
```

I'm grouping the data by their stock tickers and then looking at their respective column `Transaction` values. I'm trying to filter out the groups whose Transaction value_counts have more `Buy` than `Sale`.

I can't figure out how to do this.

I tried something like this:

`df.groupby('Stock').filter(lambda x: x.Transaction.value_counts().Buy > x.value_counts().Sale)`

which oddly doesn't work despite this working:

```
 df.Transaction.value_counts().Buy

>>>2674
```

I also tried things along the lines of

```
df.groupby('Stock').Transaction.filter(lambda x: x if x.value_counts().Buy > x.value_counts().Sale)
```

But I can't think of which pandas tools are ideal in this case.

The output can be anything from just the name of the stocks which satisfy this condition to printing out the entire group (stock name and Transaction)

So the output would be something like this

```
ADC    Buy                 2
AMNB   Buy                10
ARCC   Buy                15
ARL    Buy                12
ASA    Buy                 7
ASRV   Buy                12
       Option Exercise     1

BAC    Option Exercise    23
       Buy                15
       Sale                7
BKSC   Buy                55
BMRA   Buy                 5
       Option Exercise     3
       Sale                1
```

Or just the stock names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd `unstack` then `query`

```
d1 = df.groupby('Stock').Transaction.value_counts()
d1.unstack(fill_value=0).query('Buy > Sale')
```

[image]

We can get it back all nice a tidy with this

```
d1.unstack(fill_value=0).query('Buy > Sale') \
    .replace(0, np.nan).stack().astype(int)

Stock  Transaction    
ADC    Buy                 2
AMNB   Buy                10
ARCC   Buy                15
ARL    Buy                12
ASA    Buy                 7
ASRV   Buy                12
       Option Exercise     1
BAC    Buy                15
       Option Exercise    23
       Sale                7
BKSC   Buy                55
BMRA   Buy                 5
       Option Exercise     3
       Sale                1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Amazing. I knew there had to a simple solution. Thank you!